# Loading the youtube player API in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, youtube

I understand how to load the Youtube IFrame player API normally in a document:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

How would I do this in a meteor application though? I can't just put a `<script>` tag inside a template and I don't know if I can access `document` in one of the template helpers.

Is there some way to load it globally once the user connects for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

there are several packages which can be used to use youtube iframe api

using the package `adrianliaw:youtube-iframe-api` we can do it like below

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        player = new YT.Player("player", {
            height: "400", 
            width: "600", 

            videoId: "LdH1hSWGFGU", 
            events: {
                onReady: function (event) {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    YT.load();
}
```